# Why is the 4th book of Moses called Numbers instead of “In the Wilderness”?

Tags: hebrew, numbers

From what I understand, the Hebrew title “בְּמִדְבַּר” of the Book of Numbers literally translates to “In the Wilderness”. Why is it called Numbers instead?

Comment: biblical hermeneutics SE might be better for understanding hebrew

Comment: @depperm I thought about that - but this answer is probably more rooted in tradition rather than a hermeneutical interpretation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the wikipedia article on the [Torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah#Alternative_names), the Hebrew/Greek titles of the Torah are:

> - Bəreshit (בְּרֵאשִׁית, literally "In the beginning")—Genesis, from Γένεσις (Génesis, "Creation")
> - Shəmot (שְׁמוֹת, literally "Names")—Exodus, from Ἔξοδος (Éxodos, "Exit")
> - Vayikra (וַיִּקְרָא, literally "And He called")—Leviticus, from Λευιτικόν (Leuitikón, "Relating to the Levites")
> - Bəmidbar (בְּמִדְבַּר, literally "In the desert [of]")—Numbers, from Ἀριθμοί (Arithmoí, "Numbers")
> - Dəvarim (דְּבָרִים, literally "Things" or "Words")—Deuteronomy, from Δευτερονόμιον (Deuteronómion, "Second-Law")

You'll notice that in English, *none* of the names by which we typically refer to the books of the Bible are **incipits** like they are in Hebrew. So I'm not sure why you singled out Numbers with your question.

As with the other names originating from the Septuagint, it's based on a topic of the book. as the [Encyclopedia Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Numbers-Old-Testament) says

> The English title is a translation of the Septuagint (Greek) title referring to the numbering of the tribes of Israel in chapters 1–4.